# JHipster: Failed to initialize pool: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, jhipster

I'm trying to run JHipster application locally on my computer. I have MySQL Server installed and a `.sql` file imported via MySQL Workbench.

However, everytime I run `mvnw` in the project directory, I get:

```
    :: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.6.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2018-09-15 16:23:12.401  INFO 8296 --- [           main] com.myapp.ExampleApp                       : Starting MyApp on DESKTOP-JA21435 with PID 1234 (E:\My_projects\myapp\target\classes started by myName in E:\My_projects\myapp)
2018-09-15 16:23:12.401 DEBUG 8296 --- [           main] com.myapp.MyApp                       : Running with Spring Boot v1.3.6.RELEASE, Spring v4.2.7.RELEASE
2018-09-15 16:23:12.401  INFO 8296 --- [           main] com.myapp.MyApp                       : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2018-09-15 16:23:15.051 DEBUG 8296 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2018-09-15 16:23:18.650 DEBUG 8296 --- [           main] com.myapp.config.AsyncConfiguration      : Creating Async Task Executor
2018-09-15 16:23:19.428 DEBUG 8296 --- [           main] com.myapp.config.MetricsConfiguration    : Registering JVM gauges
2018-09-15 16:23:19.443 DEBUG 8296 --- [           main] com.myapp.config.MetricsConfiguration    : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2018-09-15 16:23:21.774  INFO 8296 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Web application configuration, using profiles: [swagger, dev]
2018-09-15 16:23:21.774 DEBUG 8296 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Initializing Metrics registries
2018-09-15 16:23:21.790 DEBUG 8296 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Registering Metrics Filter
2018-09-15 16:23:21.790 DEBUG 8296 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Registering Metrics Servlet
2018-09-15 16:23:21.790  INFO 8296 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Web application fully configured
2018-09-15 16:23:22.370 DEBUG 8296 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration   : Configuring Datasource
2018-09-15 16:23:22.887 DEBUG 8296 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration   : Configuring Liquibase
2018-09-15 16:23:22.919  WARN 8296 --- [argo-Executor-1] c.c.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2018-09-15 16:23:24.097 ERROR 8296 --- [argo-Executor-1] c.c.a.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor : Caught async exception

com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Could not create connection to database server.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:528)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:118)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:94)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
        at com.myapp.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:66)
        at com.myapp.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:49)
        at com.myapp.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

The datasource info in my `application-dev` file has the following lines which correspond to the MySQL username and password set on my PC:

```
datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myApp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
        name:
        username: root
        password: root
        hikari:
            data-source-properties:
                cachePrepStmts: true
                prepStmtCacheSize: 250
                prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
                useServerPrepStmts: true
```

Any help or pointer to what might be the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Are u running mvn with a profile? What is the command that you are executing? Is this the full log?

Comment: @JonRuddell I'm using the latest version of MySQL (8), but tried it also with older versions (5) as well and still no luck.

Comment: I was asking because I haven't been able to get it to work with MySQL 8.  I use `5.7.20` without problems

Comment: You could run your app under debugger and check that when you get this exception the effective JDBC url is what you expect. ust to verify that there isn't an issue with profile and configuration.